# onMapReady does not get called after orientation change

Tags: java, android

i am creating an app with a viewPager with fragmentPagerAdapter that contains three fragments, one of which is a Google maps API's MapFragment. i create a new fragment in the onCreate() of my MainActivity, immediately after creating it i call getMapAsync() and than add the fragment to the viewPager. my MainActivity implements the OnMapReadyCallback interface:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
```

{

private MapFragment mapFragment;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findAndInitViewPagerAndAdapter();
}

private void findAndInitViewPagerAndAdapter() {
    mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(SearchFragment.newInstance(0, mCurrentLocation), getString(R.string.first_viewPager_title));
    mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(FavoritesFragment.newInstance(1), getString(R.string.second_viewPager_title));
    if (!isTwoPane) {
        mViewPagerAdapter.addFragment(initMapFragment(), getString(R.string.third_viewPager_title));
    }
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
}

private MapFragment initMapFragment() {
    mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    return mapFragment;
}



 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
        mCurrentLocation = mLocationsManager.getLastSavedLocationFromSharedPreferences();
    }
    animateCameraToPosition(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), 2000);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);


    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            String placeID = marker.getTag().toString();
            createPlaceDetailFragment(placeID);
            mBottomBar.hideBottomNavigation(true);
        }
    });
    mMap.setOnPoiClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPoiClick(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest) {
            createPlaceDetailFragment(pointOfInterest.placeId);
            mBottomBar.hideBottomNavigation(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

this works great the first time the app is launched, but when a configuration change occurs something that i apperently do not understand happens, all of my fragments, the MapFragment among them, are recreated, the getMapAsync() method is called when i debug the app but the onMapReady callback does not and so i do not get a new GoogleMap object. nevertheless the map is created and is interactable. any additional configuration change does not change this situation. i have a method that finds my location on the map and another one that finds nearby places, both do not update the map after the first configuration change.

What am i missing?
Why dosn't the onMapReady callback get called?

Thank you

Comment: Hello @nir, have you got any solution for this ?